# How to initialize subclasses of an abstract class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to create a dark souls style text-based game. I've created an abstract class which outlines the characteristics of a dark souls class/character type. There are a couple of ways I have initialized it and I'm not sure if one is better than the other.

One important note is that in all of the subclasses, the only parameter I want is the name parameter, while all other variables will be set equal to values specific to that class/character type.

Here is one of the abstract classes I created and its subsequent subclass:

```
class Character(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, description, health, endurance, strength) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.health = health
        self.endurance = endurance
        self.strength = strength

class Giant(Character):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, description="giant", health=500, endurance=20, strength=100)
```

Here is the 2nd version:

```
class Character(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.description = ''
        self.health = 0
        self.endurance = 0
        self.strength = 0

class Giant(Character):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.description = "giant"
        self.health = 500
        self.endurance = 20
        self.strength = 100
```

Is one way better than the other? Is there a totally different way which would be better? I'm pretty new to inheritance and abstract classes and I'd appreciate any help you'd be able to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would indeed use *neither* approach, at least for what you've described here so far in this example.

Is the *only* way that different subclasses of `Character` are different that their stats are different? Or would they actually have different *behavior*?

Because if it's really only about different values, I'd instead just make `Character` a concrete rather than abstract class and then provide certain methods:

```py
class Character:
  def __init__(self, name, description, and so on):
    set the values here

  @classmethod
  def create_giant(cls, name):
    return cls(name=name, description="giant", health=500, and so on)
```

And then you'd make a giant like so:

```py
my_giant = Character.create_giant(name="Olbrzym")
```

For *your* versions, they have slightly different semantics. In your version 1, someone calling `super().__init__` will be forced to provide concrete values, whereas in version 2, they can just rely on the default values. Given that a character with `health=0` probably doesn't make sense, I'd favor version 1.

You see that my version doesn't use inheritance. When *would* I use inheritance? When I can't easily differentiate the various character types (Giant, Dwarf, Elf?) through their health and endurance and strength values alone but *actually* need different behavior.

Like, if you imagine keeping with the simple approach and you end up with code that uses a lot of constructs like

```py
if self.description == 'Giant':
  do_giant_stuff()
elif self.description == 'Dwarf':
  do_dwarf_stuff()
elif AND SO ON
```

that's a good sign you should be using inheritance instead.

EDIT:

So, to have the classes different behavior, version 1 or 2? Either would work, honestly. But there's a third way. Might be overkill but might come in handy: Hook methods.

Here's how that goes: Write things so that subclasses don't have to call `super().__init__`. Instead, write the init in the abstract class but have it call abstract methods to fill in the default values.

```py
class Character(ABC):

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.description = self._get_class_description()
    self.health = self._get_class_health()
    ...

  @abstractmethod
  def _get_class_description():
    pass

  ... same for the other attributes

class Giant(Character):
  def _get_class_description(self):
    return "giant"
  
  def _get_class_health(self):
    return 500

  ...
```

It's called the hook method because the abstract base class describes the methods that a subclass should specify (the hooks) in order to fill in the gaps in behavior.

Comment: If I did want the different character types to have different behaviors, would version 1 be the way to go, or would there be a better method for that as well?

Comment: Between 1 and 2 I'd probably pick 1. I've edited my answer to show a third way.